# When putting a table in a list, the a) ends up centered on the list, I want it on the top

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate

This is what i get:

Table Table Table

a) Table Table Table

Table Table Table

I want

a)  Table Table Table

Table Table Table

Table Table Table

I'm using enumitem and multirow.

Comment: it's best if you show what you did if you want people to tell you what you did wrong, but I assume you forgot the `[t]` for top align in `\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}...`

Comment: That fixed everything! I'll remember that next time, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To top align a tabular use

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}.....
```